# Ajax: Listsearchextender not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm using an Ajax Listsearchextender on one of my asp:DropDownList and it does not seems to behave correctly in Internet Explorer and Chrome.

In both browers, I can type my search words and hit Enter and the correct element WILL be selected, although none of the browser highlight the "suggested" option while typing. Chrome does not event change the promptText of the searchExtender while typing and in IE the opened DropDownList often covers the whole searchExtender so it is impossible to know if it's even there. Even though the searchExtender is technically working (selecting on enter), it lacks basic feedback in a way that makes it unusable in IE and Chrome.

On the other hand, in Firefox everything is working like a charm..
I'll put my code here for good measures, but since it's working in Firefox I am not sure if the problem resides there.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="lse_ddl" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="ddl" PromptCssClass="PanelSearch" PromptText="Search.."/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" style="width:350px;" runat="server"/>
```

The only styling that I do to the searchExtender is adding a border so it can be more visible..

I was wondering if those where known issues and, if so, is there a way I can fix this? I also would like to know if there is a «more recommended» way to achieve dropbox auto-suggestion than using Ajax's Listsearchextender since it does not seems to be well supported.

Thanks!

Comment: Hum, I went to https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic it seems to have been a reported issue for quite a time now. The developers don't give much feedback and it's been 8 months since the last update, overall this library doesn't seems to be well maintained. I switched over to the Chosen library (jQuery based: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ ) which does all I want and much more, while having a nicer look than Listsearchextender.

Comment: Thanks for the tip (harvesthq.github.io/chosen). Indeed this bug has been here far too long without having been fixed. I'll add my code to this post.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some help. I'm still surprised it hasn't been fixed as it's obviously not working. I don't have a lot of experience in .Net but thought ajaxToolkit was relatively commonly used..

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in the future - I had a similar issue except that Chrome worked fine for me while IE only displayed the last letter of the search prompt or anything typed into the box.  I found some information [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/5379420.aspx) that indicated you need your target control to have an appropriate width.  This works for Chrome but is not sufficient for IE.  What I found to work is to update your PromptCssClass to include both a width and a border, like this:

```
.lse 
{
    width: 250px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-style:ridge;
}
```

There are probably some other variations on this that would work, pending experimentation.  YMMV.